# PageFactory for identifying the table rows

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, html

I understand the best approach would be to use
I

```
SearchContext table = driver.FindElements(By.Xpath="xpath for the table");
List<IWebElement> allrows = table.FindElements(By.Tagname="tr");
```

But if we need to implement this in Page Factory how would we go about it. I have googled it but all the answers are for the normal method not using the `PageFactory` So Far,

```
PageFactory.InitElements(Driver, this); `Driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));`

[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//*[@id='MyGrid']/div[3]/div/table/tbody")] protected ISearchContext AccoProTable { get; set; }
```

How do i proceed to use AccProTable and search in it instead of the webpage.

Answer (score 1):

```
[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//*[@id='MyGrid']/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr")]
IList<IWebElement> allRows;
```

`PageFactory.InitElements()` can work to initialize both `IWebElement` and `IList<IWebElement>`.

More generically, your `FindsBy` would look like this:

```
[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "'xpath for the table'/tr")]
```

Comment: I implemented the change you suggested and its a good one. Simple but effective but now i am getting  **[ERROR] Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. -> Type of member 'List`1' is not IWebElement or IList<IWebElement>**  This seems to be a .Net issue according to many posts but since we already use IList<IWebElement> the range of possible fixes mentioned are fully exhausted. If you have any suggestion, its welcome. Cheers!!